# how to add numbers with an infinite number of digits using column addition?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop the addition program using column addition in javascript, For e.g: 53,22 , we add numbers from the right 3+2 and 5+2 finally results in 75, the main problem is with large numbers i am trying to develop a program which can implement addition of large numbers.so that i don't get gibberish like 1.26E+9, when adding large numbers. i tried doing it by defining the code like below

```
function add(a,b)
{

    return (Number(a) + Number(b)).toString();
}
console.log(add('58685486858601586', '8695758685'));
```

i am trying to get the added number without getting the gibberish like 5.8685496e+16

Comment: You already explained how to do it in your question. Now you just need to implement it. What's the issue? Do you not know how to iterate over the characters of a string?

Comment: i am trying it but iam looking to get efficient tips for the implementation

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency at this point. Build something that is *correct* first.

Comment: 5.8685496e+16 isn't gibberish.  It's scientific notation - which most people prefer since it stops the display of very long numbers taking up a lot of room and in general ending up unreadable.

Comment: yeah at this point i called it gibberish, because for a end user, who is a  layman with no scientific knowledge will feel that it is something they dont know.

Comment: Pretty sure it's impossible to add numbers with an infinite number of digits.

Comment: not infinite lets say for 30 digits !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them digit by digit.

```js
function sumStrings(a, b) {                                    // sum for any length
    function carry(value, index) {                             // cash & carry
        if (!value) {                                          // no value no fun
            return;                                            // leave shop
        }
        this[index] = (this[index] || 0) + value;              // add value
        if (this[index] > 9) {                                 // carry necessary?
            carry.bind(this)(this[index] / 10 | 0, index + 1); // better know this & go on
            this[index] %= 10;                                 // remind me later
        }
    }

    var array1 = a.split('').map(Number).reverse(),            // split stuff and reverse
        array2 = b.split('').map(Number).reverse();            // here as well

    array1.forEach(carry, array2);                             // loop baby, shop every item
    return array2.reverse().join('');                          // return right ordered sum
}

document.write(sumStrings('58685486858601586', '8695758685') + '<br>');
document.write(sumStrings('999', '9') + '<br>');
document.write(sumStrings('9', '999') + '<br>');
document.write(sumStrings('1', '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999') + '<br>');
```

Comment: @gabesoft,Zequ,konkked the above code compiles without loss of percision, without using the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep all values as numbers until done with all the calculations. When ready to display just format the numbers in any way you want. For example you could use `toLocaleString`.

Comment: gabesoft, your answer saved me a SLOC.but i am trying for to get it without the commas. check out my work here https://jsfiddle.net/iamSampath/oajfrqyx/

Comment: you can remove the commas with ``toLocaleString().replace(/,/g, '')``.

Comment: @Sam on the jsfiddle you posted, changing `toLocaleString` to `toString` works just as well and it outputs it without the commas, at least in chrome.

Comment: if you don't want to lose precision in your calculations you should use a big numbers library such as the one recommended by @konkked

Comment: @Zequ that's because his numbers are too small. Try .toString on this number ``176093990954464000000000000``

Comment: @gabesoft good point, thanks for clearing that up. I should just note you'll lose a bit of precision in the right most places. For example, the second log in the jsfiddle, the four last digits should be '9999' but in the log they're '0000'. For numbers that big thou, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Zequ,gabesoft , is there a way that we can use libraries suggested by konkked without mentioning them ?(like api calls instead of downloading whole jaavscirit library ?)

Comment: You could build an api endpoint in nodejs and have your server do the calculations using one of those libraries. But that seems a lot harder than just including them in your page.

Answer (score 1):

**There are several libraries for that**

A good rule of thumb is to make sure you do research for libraries before you actually go ahead and create you're own proprietary implementation of it. Found three different libraries that all solve your issue

- [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)
- [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/)
- [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

**Example**

This is how to use all three of the libraries, BigNumber coming from the bignumber.js library, Decimal from decimal.js and Big from big.js

```
var bn1 = new BigNumber('58685486858601586');
var bn2 = new BigNumber('8695758685');
console.log(bn1.plus(bn2).toString());

bn1 = new Decimal('58685486858601586');
bn2 = new Decimal('8695758685');
console.log(bn1.plus(bn2).toString());


bn1 = new Big('58685486858601586');
bn2 = new Big('8695758685');
console.log(bn1.plus(bn2).toString());
```

The console's output is :

```
58685495554360271
58685495554360271
58685495554360271
```

Comment: What are other ways of using these libraries  @konkked besides referencing them??

Comment: @Sam included examples of how to use the libraries to do what you are trying to do

Comment: i am trying to build a simple add function with the available with javascript without including any additional libraries (if i want to use additional libraries that should be made through api calls but not through th)